# reposition popup when focusing on an input

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

reposition popup when focusing on an input  (when keyboard slides up in android).

I have this problem every time i choose an input text that is located inside the popup, and this input text get the focus, The keyboard slides up and than i see just half of my popup.

I've tried to do:

```
    $("#popupNested input, #popupNested textarea").on('focus', function () {
      $("#popupNested").popup("reposition", {positionTo: 'window'});
    });
```

but this is been triggered only after pressing on the enter key on my keyboard.

Comment: would be easier to help if you include a jsfiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery mobile popup widget doesn't move when device's (android) keyboard is active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784356/jquery-mobile-popup-widget-doesnt-move-when-devices-android-keyboard-is-acti)

Comment: I've tried this and the problem remains the same, The on('focus' will fire after clicking the enter button on the android keyboard

Comment: This will trigger once an input inside a popup receives focus. Make sure you wrap your code in `pagecreate`. Add your popup's markup.

Comment: I rechecked my code, and the problem is only in the first time i select the input text - but i don't understand how this could be