# jQMobile re-positions popup window every time when Android opens own virtual keyboard - I can't input anything

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

After the following issue and answers from this and [another platform](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqmobile-re-positions-popup-window-every-time-when-android-opens-own-virtual-keyboard-i-can-t-input-anything#14737000005863885) and some advice from some wise people like Mr. Omar, I decided redesign my log-in process without any popup.

---

I've developed a PhoneGap app using Jquery Mobile 1.4.3 . My login page is a popup. And I faced with an endless process loop. The loop works with this order, Android opens its virtual keyboard, jQuery Mobile re-positioning the popup because the windows size has changed (so _handleWindowResize works in jquery.mobile.1.4.3.js and loses the focus). Android closes the virtual keyboard because there is no a focused input area. At the same time jQuery shows the popup at the center of the window but the window size has recently changed and then jQuery must show the popup at the new center of the window.

Is there any solution without breaking my jQuery Mobile library?

I can write an "If block" into the jquery library. However, it will be more difficult to manage my app.

Step by step my processes are like the following;

1. A user click the logon button
2. My popup page is opened

   ----------- first loop starts --------------
3. The user clicks the username field to type username
4. The cursor focuses the field
5. Android opens the virtual keyboard
6. Then jQuery try to reposition because the keyboard has shown and the window size has changed. So, popup hides and loses the focus.
7. Then Android virtual keyboard is hidden because there is no any active input.
8. jQuery shows the new popup without input focus

   ------------ first loop ends -----------
9. (Again) The user clicks the username field to type username
10. (Again) The cursor focuses the field
11. (Again)
12. (Again)
13. ....

### edit

I'm experiencing the problem when I click the username.

[image]

My popup markup;

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="page-login" data-theme="a"> 

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" style="height:130">
            <h1><img src="img/icons/sample.png" style="height:23px;width:96px"></h1>
        </div>    

        <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0;">
            <form id="form-login">

                    <label for="em" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="em" data-clear-btn="true" value="test@yahoo.com" placeholder="E-Mail" data-theme="a" required autofocus >
                    <label for="pw" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="pw" data-clear-btn="true" value="" placeholder="Password" data-theme="a" required>
                    <p style="text-align:right;margin:0;"><span><a href="#page-password-reset" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="mini-text-link">I forgot password</a></span></p>

                <hr class="thin">
                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="twin-buttons ui-block-a">
                        <small><button type="submit" id="login-submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Login</button></small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="twin-buttons ui-block-b" >
                        <small><a type="button" id="login-cancel" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ">İptal</a></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type='hidden' name='_csrf' value='null'>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4 style="font-size:10px">
                <span><a href="#page-register" class="mini-text-link">Sign up</a></span>
            </h4>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Post your popup markup and when do you focus on input.

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks I've updated my questions. Do you need another thing?

Comment: is page div `data-role=page` is the direct parent of the popup or is it inside another wrapper?

Comment: Popup direct parent should be page div. don't wrap it in any other div.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've changed. I think I should examine some more time. I had developed using jQuery and Sails.js (EmbeddedJS). I had to take my codes using copy/paste from browser. And after I took my codes into cordova I've experienced some weird cases.

Comment: Ok. I've made sorter my codes and I've tried again. At my first test, I've experienced same thing again. But just the first time. At second time everything were OK. I didn't change anything. But now, everything works properly.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20786836/1771795 and see if does any difference.

Comment: Omar thank you very much :) , this is just like my problem. I've researched today for hours but I couldn't find that entry. I increased your answer point.

Comment: Should I delete this question now?

Comment: You're welcome. It's up to you whether to delete it or vote to close it as a duplicate of the other question :)

Comment: It's strange. I've been trying the app on my phone. I have just two inputs and two buttons. I've uploaded my popup's image. When I clicked email field, I'm having the same problem. Clearly the problem's reason is that the virtual keyboard cannot overlap the Popup. So, my popup is too big for this purpose. Unless jQuery Mobile allows that our works are difficult. When I mark as comment the handleWindowResize method, popup works suitable with virtual keyboard.

Comment: Really... If I click the password everything is good. But if I click the username I never type anything :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65487/discussion-between-omar-and-user3765109).

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, and I fix it by update JQM javascript.

```
_handleWindowResize: function(/* theEvent */) {
    if ( this._isOpen && this._ignoreResizeTo === 0 ) {
        if ( ( this._expectResizeEvent() || this._orientationchangeInProgress ) &&
            !this._ui.container.hasClass( "ui-popup-hidden" ) ) {
            // effectively rapid-close the popup while leaving the screen intact
            if(!((':focus').is('input') || $(':focus').is('textarea'))){//judge user is in input mode or not.
                this._ui.container
                .addClass( "ui-popup-hidden ui-popup-truncate" )
                .removeAttr( "style" ); 
            }
        }
    }
},
```

It's not best solution, but useful for me.